# How to create panel with JTable and GridBagLayout under?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gridbaglayout

Is there a chance to create one panel with a `Jtable` and a `GridBagLayout` in one place?

I want to have a `JTable` and a `GridBagLayout` with filtering buttons, but when I add the table and the buttons in the `GridBagLayout`, those buttons appears behind the table.

This is my code:

```
public class FormConnected extends JPanel {



private JTextField tfId = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfName = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfSurname = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfYear = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfAge = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfSchoolName = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfCity = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfDeanName = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField tfYearOfBuild = new JTextField(10);
private JLabel lFrom = new JLabel("From");
private JLabel lTo = new JLabel("To");
private JCheckBox jcbStudentName = new JCheckBox("Student name");
private JCheckBox jcbStudentSurname = new JCheckBox("Student surname");
private JCheckBox jcbSchoolCity = new JCheckBox("School city");
private JCheckBox jcbSchoolName = new JCheckBox("School name");
private JCheckBox jcbStudentAge = new JCheckBox("Student age");
private JList jlStudentName = new JList();
private JList jlStudentSurname = new JList();
private JList jlSchoolName = new JList();
private JList jlSchoolCity = new JList();
private JButton bFiltrate = new JButton("Filtrate");
private JButton bReset = new JButton("Reset");
private JComboBox jcbFrom = new JComboBox();
private JComboBox jcbTo = new JComboBox();

JPanel panelUp;
JPanel panelMedium;
JPanel panelDown;

private ArrayList<Connected> list;
private int idx;

public ArrayList<Connected> getLista() {
    return list;
}

public void setLista(ArrayList<Connected> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public int getIdx() {
    return idx;
}

public void setIdx(int idx) {
    this.idx = idx;
}
public FormConnected()
{
    super(new GridBagLayout());
    //add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new MyCustomTableModel(Database.selectInnerJoin()))));
    JPanel panelUp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbcPanelUp = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel panelMedium = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbcPanelMedium = new GridBagConstraints();

    JPanel panelDown = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbcPanelDown = new GridBagConstraints();



    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 0;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 0;
    gbcPanelUp.ipadx = 5;
    gbcPanelUp.ipady = 5;
    gbcPanelUp.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    panelUp.add(jcbStudentName, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 1;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 0;
    panelUp.add(jcbStudentSurname, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 2;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 0;
    panelUp.add(jcbSchoolCity, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 3;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 0;
    panelUp.add(jcbSchoolName, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 0;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 1;
    panelUp.add(jlStudentName, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 1;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 1;
    panelUp.add(jlStudentSurname, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 2;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 1;
    panelUp.add(jlSchoolCity, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 3;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 1;
    panelUp.add(jlSchoolName, gbcPanelUp);


    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 0;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 2;
    panelUp.add(jcbStudentAge, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 0;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 3;
    panelUp.add(lFrom, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 1;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 3;
    panelUp.add(jcbFrom, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 2;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 3;
    panelUp.add(lTo, gbcPanelUp);

    gbcPanelUp.gridx = 3;
    gbcPanelUp.gridy = 3;
    panelUp.add(jcbTo, gbcPanelUp);


    gbcPanelDown.gridx = 0;
    gbcPanelDown.gridy = 0;
    gbcPanelDown.ipadx = 10;
    gbcPanelDown.ipady = 10;
    gbcPanelDown.insets = new Insets(50, 50, 5, 50);
    panelDown.add(bFiltrate, gbcPanelDown);

    gbcPanelDown.gridx = 1;
    gbcPanelDown.gridy = 0;
    gbcPanelDown.insets = new Insets(50, 50, 5, 50);
    panelDown.add(bReset, gbcPanelDown);


    GridBagConstraints gbcMain = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbcMain.gridx = 0;
    gbcMain.gridy = 0;
    add(panelUp, gbcMain);

    gbcMain.gridx = 0;
    gbcMain.gridy = 1;
    add(panelDown, gbcMain);

    list = Database.selectInnerJoin();
    if (list != null)
    {
        idx = 0;
        fillFormConnected();
    }
}
public void fillFormConnected()
{
    if(list.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        tfId.setText(list.get(idx).getId()+ "");
        tfName.setText(list.get(idx).getName()+ "");
        tfSurname.setText(list.get(idx).getSurname()+ "");
        tfYear.setText(list.get(idx).getYear()+"");
        tfAge.setText(list.get(idx).getAge()+"");
        tfSchoolName.setText(list.get(idx).getSchoolName()+"");
        tfCity.setText(list.get(idx).getCity()+"");
        tfDeanName.setText(list.get(idx).getDeanName()+"");
        tfYearOfBuild.setText(list.get(idx).getYearOfBuild()+"");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You have defined three panels. Exaclty in which one do you want the table to appear?

Comment: I have 3 panels yes:Up,Down,Medium In this three panels I want to have only filtrate buttons and methods but above I want to have JTable to see results of filtration. I should put my JTable in one of this Panel??

Comment: Ah! Now I got your problem. I guest that you are adding the JTable directly to the main JPanel (FormConnected). That way you positioned it in the 0,0 coordinates of the main grid, the same position of panelUp. Just position your panels in 0,1  0,2 and 0,3 (modifying conveniently your gbcMain constraints.

Comment: I hope that I made myself clear. If you do not got the idea, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Firstly thx very much to correct my english. Great that work!!:D:D I put upPanel in grid 1, DownPanel in grid 2 so JTable autmaticly is positioned on 0!! :D Thank You very very much!!